# Qt - "This does not seem to be a debug build" after clean and rebuilding

Tags: c++, qt, debugging, qmake

I have a Qt console application with the following in the .pro file:

```
QT += core gui

CONFIG += c++11
CONFIG += release
greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets
TARGET=Test
TEMPLATE=app
SOURCES += main.cpp
```

Some of these are changed since I want to turn the project into a GUI application. However, when I try to debug (F5), a window pops up saying that "This does not seem to be a Debug build". The situation does not change even if I choose the Debug build configuration in the build settings.

Then I created another project. I found out that if I clean and rebuild the project, "This does not seem to be a Debug build" will start to pop up. What should I do to solve this problem?

Edit: I checked and I do have the CONFIG += debug flag in my `qmake`. The entire command is

```
qmake /media/henryw/Files/Test/Test.pro -r -spec linux-g++-64 CONFIG+=debug
```

Answer (score 2):

I have found a solution. I am not sure if it is good practice but solves the problem.

Changing the line

```
CONFIG += release
```

to

```
CONFIG += console
```

followed by cleaning and rebuilding causes the warning to no longer show up.